# IOPCShutdown::Advise Failed : error 80040202

Tags: c++, com, opc, dcom

I broke my head while looking for the cause of this error (4 days)

- I have an OPC DA server running in a remote machine.
- The OPC DA client is located in another machine.

in the client implementation I create an external instance via `CoCreateInstanceEx()`

```
HRESULT result = ::CoCreateInstanceEx(clsid, NULL, clsctx, sinptr, 1, &mqi);
PRINT_COMERRORIF(result, "CoCreateInstanceEx failed");
```

and it works fine and I get a pointer to the remote OPC server (`mqi.pItf`)

the problem comes when I call the `advise()` function of `IConnectionPoint` interface

I specify that I found the connection point and I return a pointer to the IOPCShutdown interface (`_MY_shutdown`) before calling the advise function

```
result = server_object->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer 
(void**)&connection_point_container);
PRINT_COMERRORIF(result, CTXID(this) "No IConnectionPointContainer interface");

result = connection_point_container->FindConnectionPoint(IID_IOPCShutdown, &_MY_shutdown);
PRINT_COMERRORIF(result, CTXID(this) "No IOPCShutdown connection point found");

result = _MY_shutdown->Advise(_MY_shutdown_callback, &_MY_shutdown_cookie); // HERE IS THE ISSUE 
PRINT_COMERRORIF(result, CTXID(this) "IOPCShutdown::Advise Failed");
```

and I got this error:

```
IOPCShutdown::Advise Failed : error 80040202
```

I've checked the [DCOM Setting for Discovery of Remote OPC Servers configuration](https://www.ge.com/digital/documentation/ifix/version61/Subsystems/DAConfig/content/setting_up_dcom_for_discovery_of_remote_opc_servers.htm) and I did everything as described but no way ;(

Here is my configuration:

Server side

```
 - OPC DA Server installed and running

 - local user account is created

 - DCOM settings are configured as required

 - Policy settings are configured as well
```

Client side

```
 - OPC DA client interface installed.

 - local user accounts are created on the both Nodes. Accounts have the same 
   name and passwords like on the server.
```

firewall is disabled in both server/client.

Comment: Error 0x80040202 uses FACILITY_ITF so it's specific to this IOPCShutdown::Advise. You should ask the vendor what it means. Otherwise, wild guess, have you checked your thread is running as STA or MTA. Many servers (especially for events) support one or the other (w/o being explicitly documented).

Comment: @SimonMourier to see threads I need to install Process Monitor or similair, the problem that I don't have the rights ...

Comment: Your code executes in threads, just dumps the thread state using this for example: IComThreadingInfo::GetCurrentApartmentType

Comment: Wrong comment, it is IConnectionPoint::Advice that failed.  Gives a hint at the underlying problem, for callbacks things work in reverse.  It has to be you that implements IOPCShutdown, the server calls your interface's QueyInterface to obtain the IOPCShutdown interface pointer.  If that fails then Advice() returns 0x80040202 (aka CONNECT_E_NOCONNECTION).

Comment: @HansPassant I think  `::FindConnectionPoint()` returns a pointer to IOPCShutdown interface if it is a supported outgoing interface and this result didn't fail. the problem is `::Advise()` when tried to establish the connection between the connection point (last pointer) and the client sink. I don't see the source of this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I change the authentification level of my OPC DA server in DCOM Config from "Connect" to "None", I don't know why but it works ^^

Answer (score 1):

Have you properly configured DCOM and policy settings on a **Client** side?
As mentioned in comments, because for asynchronous connections (when callback is invoked) your client behaves as a server and server - as a client.